# c# listBox DisplayMember

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

c# WinForms.Listbox.

```
listBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Question";
listBox1.ValueMember = "idQuestion";

//for ValueMember showing...   
textBox2.Text = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

//What I must use for DisplayMember showing?  
textbox3.Text = ??????????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That may not be so easy with untyped tables. A Combobox has a Text property, for the listbox:

```
 textbox3.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Gets you the 'item' but that probably is a DataRowView. You can cast it :
`((DataRowViw) SelectedItem).Row[3]`

Comment: //I used this construction.It's work fine, but does it correct?                            textBox3.Text = ((DataRowView)listBox1.SelectedItem).Row[1].ToString();

Comment: If it works it's OK. Also there is a deleted answer here suggesting Listbox.Text

Answer (score 1):

**This will work with you**
textbox3.Text = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);