# Format ListBox Items bound to a Datatable in C#

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

I have a Datatable with a field named "path" that stores full path of a file. I have bound the "path" field to a listbox. The listbox shows the full file path but I want to format the path so it only shows the file name instead of full file path yet remains bound with "path" field that has full file path stored. Is there any way to do it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Modify your source/sql to return `filename` and `filepath` in datatable then `Bind` FileName to `DataTextField` and FilePath to `DataValue` field of listbox

Comment: Try wtapping System.IO.Path.GetFilename(path) around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is value member and display member.

This might help: [c# listBox DisplayMember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008022/c-sharp-listbox-displaymember)